# What is the relation between maximal tori of $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is the relation between maximal tori of $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$?

Maximal torus is defined as the maximal abelian subgroup that is connected. For $U(n)$ it is the following:

[image]

The article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus) then adds that "A maximal torus in the special unitary group $SU(n) \subset U(n)$ is just the intersection of $T$ and $SU(n)$ which is a torus of dimension $n − 1$."

**My questions are:**

1. Why is the torus of $SU(n)$ intersection of $T$ of $U(n)$ with $SU(n)$?
2. If we take $n = 2$, does this simply mean that $T$ of $U(2)$ is of dimension $1$, so it is somehow homeomorphic to a circle..?
3. What does the notation "$e^{i \theta_1}$... mean? (I am sorry I am not very familiar with this, I study mostly different parts of Maths).

Thank you very much!

Comment: $e^z$ is the exponential function which can be defined for complex $z$ as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n/n!$. In this particular case, when $z=i\theta$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ it is just $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$.

Comment: You should be careful with the articles: There is (in general) not "the" maximal torus. The diagonal matrices are "a" maximal torus, i.e. just one, and there are many others. For example, any conjugate of a maximal torus is again another maximal torus. For such other maximal tori, you could ask the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order:

1. Well $T\cap SU(n)$ is also a torus since it is still abelian and connected so you just need to see that it is maximal. It shouldn't be too hard to convince yourself that a matrix which commutes with all the (determinant 1) diagonal matrices must be diagonal itself (so in $T$) and since it is supposed to be in $SU(n)$ it must be in our torus $T\cap SU(n)$ so it is maximal.
2. Yes. Indeed here it is exactly given as the set of matrices:
   $$ T \cap SU(2) = \left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}
   \end{pmatrix}\right|\theta \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

This is clearly isomorphic to the unit circle in the complex plane: $\left\{\left.e^{i\theta} \in \mathbb{C} \right|\theta \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$. We could replace $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ by $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ of course.

3. $e^{i\theta}$ is just a complex number (of unit length) written in polar form: $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$